# Angular 2 Input Directive Modifying Form Control Value

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have a simple Angular 2 directive that modifies the input value of a textbox. Note that i'm using the Model-Driven form approach.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appUpperCase]'
})
export class UpperCaseDirective{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) {

  }

  @HostListener('input',['$event']) onEvent($event){
    console.log($event);
    let upper = this.el.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase();
    this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(upper);

  }

}
```

The dom updates properly, however the model updates after every other keystroke. Take a look at the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qKM1Fpfwanub3nFoSMTA?p=preview)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This thrills me because I encountered this earlier and was left scratching my head.

Revisiting the issue, what you need to do is to change your `this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(upper)` where the ControlValueAccessor is explicitly writing to the DOM element and not to the control itself to instead call

```
 this.control.control.setValue(upper);
```

which will change the value on the control and be correctly reflected both on the page and in the control's property.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html

> A ControlValueAccessor abstracts the operations of writing a new value
>   to a DOM element representing an input control.

Here's a forked plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rllNyE07uPhUA6UfiLkU?p=preview

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: What about character position? Keypress sends character position to end of input.

Comment: @silntsod Do you have any idea, how to use it with template driven form ? with ngModel

Comment: Thank you for this great answer

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something like this, but when I tried the code in my project I was getting errors on the line this.el.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase() as per the working example above given by @silentsod.

I amended the code to:

```
let str:string = this.control.value;
this.control.control.setValue(str.toUpperCase());
```

Here's a forked plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uf6udp7mQYmnKX6hGPpR?p=preview