# Last character does not get capitalize

Tags: angular, directive

I am creating a directive to uppercase string inputted by user.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[upperCase]'
})
export class UppercaseDirective {
    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef
        ){}

    @HostListener('keyup') onKeyUp() {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase();

    }
}
```

When getting the value in component, the last character is still in lower case, but when i traced it inside the directive, it shows that the whole string is in uppercase.

Does anyone else experienced this problem and has any workaround?

Comment: I think your requirement is to be a textbox with it's value should be capital. Right? Then, you can manage it through the css itself. Give the style "text-transform: uppercase" to your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682717/angular-2-input-directive-modifying-form-control-value)

haven't tried the on keydown and keypress though as the above solution works for me